# Html datatables data to be accessed in typescript component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables

> I want to access the chosen mfRowsOnPage. For example now it is 10.
>   Later the user might choose 5 or 15. I need this data in component. I
>   even want to get which page data is shown to the user. Example 1st
>   page or 2nd page , so on.

**this is my table.**

```
<table class="table" [mfData]="stacklist_table| selectedcolumn | search : searchQuery | filter: addFilter : selected" #stacklist="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let colValues of stacklist.data | column: '' : ''">
                <mfDefaultSorter by="{{colValues}}">{{colValues|translate}}</mfDefaultSorter>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr draggable *ngFor="let stack of stacklist.data" [dragOverClass]="'drag-over-border'" [dragData]="stack" [class.active]="checkIfStackElementIsSelected(stack)" (click)="setStacklistRow(stack, $event)">
              <td *ngFor="let rowValues of stack | row">{{ rowValues }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr style="height: 50px;">
              <td colspan="6">
                <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[50,100,150]" style="position:fixed; margin-top: -15px"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
                <!-- <mfBootstrapPaginator [hidden]='!hideElement' (dblclick)="eventEmitDoubleClick($event)" [rowsOnPageSet]="totalVisibleCount"></mfBootstrapPaginator> -->
                <!-- <input [hidden]='hideElement' [(ngModel)]="newCount" (click)="doneEditing(newCount)" autofocus /> -->
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr (click)="loadMoreStackElements()">Load more</tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
```

How do I go about it?
I am new to it and not understanding the way to access this data.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

Comment: I tried accessing mfRowsOnPage but I cant do that way.

Comment: Neither can i access  [(ngModel)]="mfRowsOnPage"

Comment: `<tr *ngFor="#item of mf.data">` is not supported in recent versions of Angular. It needs to be `<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">`

Comment: Check now. The real implememtation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `[attr.mfRowsOnPage]='10'` and check if that works.